# symbolic data on plot in latex

Tags: pgfplots, symbols, plot

I want to plot some data and for one of them I want to show (0.1,Inf), where Inf stands for infinity. Also, I want yaxis to be in log-scale. I have attached a sample photo of what I want to plot.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can do this?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: With `pstricks`, it is very simple: an optional argument  of the command `\psaxes` sets the labels for the axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! Sure, you can do that. Here is an example.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[declare function={myinf=10^6;},ymode=log,
    ymin=100,ymax=10^6,
    yticklabel={\ifnum\ticknum=4
    Inf
    \else
    $10^{\the\numexpr\ticknum+2}$
    \fi}]
  \addplot[mark=star,thick] coordinates {(0.1,myinf) (0.3,myinf) (0.5,10^3)};
  \addplot[color=red,mark=o] coordinates {(0.1,10^4.5) (0.3,10^4.1) (0.5,10^4)};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The functions `Inf` and `inf` are already taken, so I call the function `myinf`. Yet this example shows how you can get any symbolic value in the Ti*k*Z-pgfplots ecosystem: just declare a function. This can then be used in plots. Changing the ticks is a very standard task in pgfplots.

If you post a code of a use case, there will be a much more automatic solution possible, but at this point I have no idea what you are up to.

Comment: thank you so much